# Removing numbers and separators from a numbered list

Tags: regex

I am often dealing with list that users submit to a web site. A list usually looks like:

1. Item
2. Item

The pattern is usually a number followed by the separator (it can be "-" or "\" or "." or any other typical separators). There can be one or more spaces between the number and separator and between the separator and the list item. Sometimes there is no number in front of the list item and in that case nothing needs to be done. Sometimes there is a number but no separator.

Is there a way to take out the number and/or the separator all together using regular expression?

Comment: what language are you parsing in? Javascript? PHP? Ruby? C#? Etc

Comment: I am using C# to do the parsing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will match numbers and separators and the beginning of a line:

```
^\d+\s*[-\\.)]?\s+
```

Use it to replace it with an empty strings (depends on the language you are using).

You might have to add more characters to the character class, to match possible separators.

Good source to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I think you want `\d+`.  Everything else has to be optional, but if you don't require at least one digit, what's the point?

Comment: @Alan: Ah, well I took *Sometimes there is no number in front of the list item* too literal I guess... ;) Thanks, updated.

Comment: Keep reading: "...and in that case nothing needs to be done."  In other words, if there isn't at least one digit followed by at least one space (I misspoke about that earlier), the regex should fail to match.

Comment: @Alan: oh, have to remove the `?` after all of that... thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=\d*\s*[-\\.]?\s*)([a-zA-Z\s*]+)
```

You can view the answer here: [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2u6ab)

```
Explanation:

\d*- matches 0 or more occurrence digits
\s* - matches 0 or more occurrence whitespace after the number
[-\\.]? - matches 0 or 1 occurrence of '-' '.' '\'
\s* - matches 0 or more occurrence whitespace after that
([a-zA-Z\s*]+) -matches any characters after that (items you need to extract)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it looks like it captures each word after the separator. If I have: 1. item one two, it will capture "item", "one", "two" separately. I am looking for a way to get rid of the number and/or separator and keep the rest of the item as one.

Comment: Updated my answer. This will work, just add `\s*` to it: `(?=\d*\s*[-\\.]?\s*)([a-zA-Z\s*]+)` . you can view it here [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2u6ab)