# Regex to remove track number from song name?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a ListView that display song names and artists. Sometimes, the song names contain the track number and a separator with some in this format

```
13 - J. Cole - Best Friend
```

and others like this

```
13 - Beautiful People
```

After some digging around I found that the best way to go about this is to define a regex pattern that will remove any unnecessary characters in the string. Cool. I've looked at other SO questions on a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628135/removing-numbers-and-separators-from-a-numbered-list) and a couple blog posts but still no luck.

This my first time dealing with regular expressions and I find it quite useful, just trying to wrap my head around coming up with efficient/useful patterns.

Here's what I need to remove from the string if it is a match

```
The track number
The "-" or whatever separator character that follows it
The artist name and the "-" that follows that(Each artist name is listed below the   song, so it would be redundant)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as usual guys, thanks!

Edit: The same output that  I would like is something like this, with just the song names. No track numbers, and if applicable; no artist names following the "-"

```
Beautiful People
Angel of Mine
Human Nature
```

Comment: computers are deterministic. they cannot work with definitions such as "whatever separator character that follows it". other than that you can use `\d+\s*-\s*([^-]+){1,2}` or something like that. if the dash character is not the only possible separator then please define that.

Comment: what will be the sample output??? you only want to remove the track number? or also the - in between the string

Comment: @StinePike I've edited my question. Basically remove the track number and hyphen that follows it. There's also cases where the artist name is also listed as part of the song title. Would be nice if I can remove that as well

Comment: @akonsu Good poiint. The separator is usually a "-", but I've seen cases where the track number is followed by a "." period. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible regex you could use:

```
name.replaceFirst("^\\d+\\.?\\s*-(?:.*?-)?\\s*", "")
```

This takes out:

1. digits at the front
2. optionally followed by a dot
3. optionally spaces
4. a hyphen
5. if a further hyphen is found, then everything up to that
6. optionally spaces

Answer (score 2):

A piece of code will be better to give you a hint:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] songNames = {
            "1 - my awesome artist - go beyond",
            "2 - such is life",
            "My awesome song"
        };



        Pattern trackNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("^ *\\d+ *- *");
        Pattern artistPattern = Pattern.compile(" *- *[^-]+ *- *");

        Matcher matcher;

        for(String song: songNames) {

            matcher = trackNumberPattern.matcher(song);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                song = matcher.replaceFirst("");
            }

            matcher = artistPattern.matcher(song);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                song = matcher.replaceFirst("");
            }

            System.out.println(">>> " + song);

        }
    }

}
```

You can find the doc to write regex in java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

DISCLAIMER: This won't work properly if some of the song names or artist names contain dashes (-), etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex (a little bit radical):

```
^\\d*+\\W*+\\b(?>[^-]++-\\s++(?=\w))?
```

and replace it by nothing.

this will destroy all digits followed by non-word characters at the begining, and the interpret name if it is present